# Find all possible combinations with replacement in a string

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

Here's the code I have so far:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

string = "abcd012345"

char = "01268abc"

for i, j in combinations(tuple(range(len(string))), 2):
    for char1, char2 in product(char, char):
        print(string[:i] + char1 + string[i+1:j] + char2 + string[j+1:])
```

So, the string is abcd012345, and I change two characters in order to find all possible combinations. The characters are 01268abc. In this example, we got 2880 combinations.

The goal is to **set** what character(s) will be in a specified place of the string. Example below:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

string = "abcd012345"
# place   0123456789      

char_to change_for_place0 = "ab02"
char_to change_for_place1 = "14ah"
char_to change_for_place2 = "94nf"
char_to change_for_place3 = "a"
char_to change_for_place4 = "9347592"
char_to change_for_place5 = "93478nvg"
char_to change_for_place6 = "b"
char_to change_for_place7 = ""
char_to change_for_place8 = ""
char_to change_for_place9 = "84n"

for i, j in combinations(tuple(range(len(string))), 2):
    for char1, char2 in product(char, char):
        print(string[:i] + char1 + string[i+1:j] + char2 + string[j+1:])
```

**Note**:

1. some places can be empty and stays the same as in the place 7 and 8.
2. the number of *places* will be 64.
3. the number of characters to change will be 4, not 2 as in the example.

I will enjoy to learn from your solutions and ideas, thank you.

Comment: Okay, so **what is your question** about the task? "I will enjoy to learn from your solutions and ideas, thank you." is [not appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/) for Stack Overflow, as this is **not a discussion forum**. Instead: **what happens** when you try your code? If there is not an actual, concretely identified problem, then there is not a suitable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boils down to adding the current letter of each position inside `string` to your current replacements for that position and then creating all possible combinations of those options:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

string = "abcd012345"

# must be of same lenght as (string), each entry correspond to the same index in string
p = ["ab02", "14ah", "94nf", "a", "9347592", "93478nvg", "b", "", "", "84n"]  

errmsg = f"Keep them equal lenghts: '{string}' ({len(string)}) vs {p} ({len(p)})"
assert len(p)==len(string), errmsg

# eliminates duplicates from letter in string + replacments due to frozenset()
d = {idx: frozenset(v + string[idx]) for idx, v in enumerate(p)} 

# creating this list take memory
all_of_em = [''.join(whatever) for whatever in product(*d.values())]

# if you hit a MemoryError creating the list, write to a file instead
# this uses a generator with limits memory usage but the file is going
# to get BIG 
# with open("words.txt","w") as f:
#    for w in (''.join(whatever) for whatever in product(*d.values())):
#        f.write(w+"\n")

print(*all_of_em, f"\n{len(all_of_em)}", sep="\t")
```

Output:

```
2and2g234n      2and2g2348      2and2g2344      2and2g2345      2and27b34n      
[...snipp...]
249d99234n      249d992348      249d992344      249d992345      
100800
```

If you value the order of letters in your replacements, use

```
d = {idx: (v if string[idx] in v else string[idx]+v) for idx, v in enumerate(p)}
```

instead:

```
abcd012345      abcd012348      [...]     2hfa2gb344      2hfa2gb34n      115200
```

The difference in amounts is due to duplicate `9` in "9347592" wich is removed using frozensets.

---

To get only those that changed fewer then 5 things:

```
# use a generator comprehension to reduce memory usage
all_of_em = (''.join(whatever) for whatever in product(*d.values()))

# create the list with less then 5 changes from the generator above
fewer = [w for w in all_of_em if sum(a != b for a, b in zip(w, string)) < 5]
```

Comment: @perm  `with open("words.txt","w") as f: for w in fewer: f.write(w+"\n")`

Comment: @permpyt  Use `==`

Comment: @permpyt  You seem to try to create a password cracker os such - I dont feel like participating in that. If you have 64 places and at max 4 of them changes for 4-6 different things, creating _all_ and then filtering down to 0,1,2,3,4 changing ones is inefficient. i changed and modified my answer multiple times and answered very basic things (= vs ==) f.e. - you might want to do less complicated things or ask a new question so some other ppl help you out. [I am out.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)